# Inserting data in mysql table with javascript / AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

When the user clicks a button i want to update a value in mysql table, but somehow I'm doing something wrong and nothing happens.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id= "openchest" onclick="insertvalue();"> Open </button>
```

**javascript**

```
function insertvalue(){
   makeRequest('addgold.php');
}
```

EDIT: changed the javascript BUT it still doesnt do anything.. 
the addgold.php doesnt show any mysql error.

```
function insertvalue(){



$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
            url: "addgold.php",
            cache: false,
            data:{id:'openchest'},
            }).done(function( msg ) {  console.log(msg);
                });

}
```

**addgold.php**

```
<?php include ("connection.php"); 
if(isset($_REQUEST)) {    
      $sql= "UPDATE members SET coins = coins + 10 WHERE id ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id'])."' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);    
}
?>
```

Comment: You're doing `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: can you please add `$error = mysqli_error($link)` line after the mysqli_query and dump the $error?

Comment: done. there is no error. it just doesnt add/update the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to use ajax function on click and dont forget to include jquery libray    

function insertvalue(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
                url: "addgold.php",
                cache: false,
                data:{id:'anything'},
                }).done(function( msg ) {  console.log(msg);
                    });

    }
```

Comment: thanks, but it still doesnt work. when I click the button nothing happens